# How to set the minimum size of the button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, layout, constraints, minimum-size

I'm building a Flutter web app in which I have a button which contains an icon and some text in a row. My problem is, that whenever the user resizes the window to a smaller size, the button gets too small, leaving the text sticking out of it. I tried to give it constraints and set the minimum size of the button on the style parameter but it didn't help.


The button before resizing the window (default size):
[image]

The button after the window becomes small:
[image]

The code of the button widget:

```
class UploadTextButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function _onPressed;

  const UploadTextButton(this._onPressed);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxWidth: 250,
        maxHeight: 50,
        minWidth: 200,
        minHeight: 50
      ),
      child: OutlinedButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(200, 50))
        ),
          onPressed: () => _onPressed(),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                child: Icon(Icons.cloud_upload),
              ),
              Text("Upload my new picture")
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrap it in flexible widget

Answer (score 0):

if problem is with the test sizing you can use `Fittedbox()` widget for text.

```
FittedBox(
child:Text("Upload my new picture"),)
```

Comment: Didn't help, still gets too small.

Answer (score -2):

you can define the button size in app theme

eg:

```
     buttonTheme: const ButtonThemeData(

     buttonColor: assentColor,
 
     padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),

      minWidth: double.maxFinite,
 
     colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(brightness: 
  
    Brightness.dark),
    
     ),
```

Comment: I don't want to resize every button in my app.